# How to make a java client use a socket to connect to a server not on my computer?

Tags: java, networking

I know how to make a socket between a server and client if they are both on my computer. What I don't understand is how to make a socket connection between a client on my computer, and my server running on a different network. I can't just do:
new Socket("Machine name", PortNumber);
right?

Comment: Sure you can, if the machine name is in DNS or your `hosts` file.

Comment: So do I use the IP address as the "machine name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a socket with a hostname or ip address. However this does not work in Java applets: They typically are restricted to only connect to the machine the web page has been loaded from. Similar restriction (Java does this with a special SecurityManager) applies to some old fashioned and strict application servers.

But with stand-alone Java programs nothing is stopping you from doing it. If you have problems it might be best to tell us what error message you get.